# Why does my imported image have such a low quality in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I import a high quality PNG image (made in photoshop in Unity, it instantly becomes very low-quality. What is the cause of this problem?

EDIT: This project on which I'm working on is a mobile game, so the picture is taken from inside my phone on play mode.

[image]

original PNG vs Unity import

COMPRESSION SETTINGS:

[image]

Comment: What kind of device? What are the compression settings you are using?

Comment: What does it look like when it's not rotated?

Comment: The device which I'm using is a Samsung Galaxy A50, and you can find the compression settings in the original post

Comment: It's still blurry when it's not rotated.

Answer (score 0):

click on the sprite and try the following inspector settings:

filter mode: Point (no filter)

Compression: None

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work.